# spring-boot web app fails to start : Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to start my spring-boot-web app but I'm getting the following error :

```
2020-03-17 20:54:22.643  WARN 15640 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
2020-03-17 20:54:22.664 ERROR 15640 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

I configured the following ApplicationContext file :

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"repos"})
public class AppConfig  {
    @Bean
    public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("mydb");

        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

I need those beans because in one of my services I inject the following objects :

```
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

and my main app :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        //load the spring config class we configured
        SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class);
    }
```

my dependencies in pom.xml :

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

Solutions I tried but didnt work :

1)add extends SpringBootServletInitializer to both Application.java and Appconfig.java

2)Move the beans from the AppConfig.java to Application.java

3)Tried to set the following annotation on  the application class :

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
```

4)Adding the following dependency to the pom.xml :

org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-tomcat
        2.2.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 4):

I resolved my problem by adding dependancy 'spring-boot-starter-web'.

Comment: Fixed my problem! 

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your filename, class name and the name of the class inside the SpringApplication.run() function are the same.
Also, make sure you haven't forgotten the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

Comment: Do now upload Images,  Read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

You can comment the `<scope>provided</scope>` in pom.xml file like below

[image: See the sample snippet belo]

Answer (score 0):

My solution : 
In addition to the persistence.xml file I created application.properties file : 
    # Connection url for the database
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://ip:port/db
    spring.datasource.username=postgres
    spring.datasource.password=postgres
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto =update
    spring.jpa.show-sql = true
    chosen database
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
    spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
    server.port = 9091

Afterwards, in my Application.java I added the following annotations and extend :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("repositories")
@EntityScan("dao")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

Answer (score 0):

I was fixing this because of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1924298

And my fix was to do this in pom.xml only:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

No changes in classes or config were needed.

Answer (score 0):

Add 3.1.1 in to properties like below than fix issue

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

Just Update Project => right click => Maven=> Update Project

Answer (score -2):

You need to override configure method from SpringBootServletInitializer

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}
```